# How to set a fixed VisibleRange for the YAxis?

Tags: c#, wpf, scichart

I'm attempting to implement a SciChart without AutoRange on the YAxis.  However, it seems to be completely ignoring my range entirely.

I've tried setting my YAxis to a NumericAxisViewModel with a fixed DoubleRange of -5000 to 5000, but it always shows a range of 0 to 10.  While stepping through the debugger I can clearly see that the NumericAxis is accepting my DoubleRange but when the chart finally renders, it's 0 to 10 only.  This YAxis is later being added to an Observable collection called YAxes which is being bound in XAML.

Axis construction

```
            this.YAxis = new NumericAxisViewModel
            {
                AxisAlignment = AxisAlignment.Left,
                DrawMajorGridLines = false,
                DrawMinorGridLines = false,
                DrawMajorBands = false,
                VisibleRange = new DoubleRange(5000, -5000),
                Visibility = Visibility.Visible,
                Id = channel.Id.ToString(),
            };
```

Higher view model is collecting the data

```cs
            foreach (IDataChannelViewModel d in this.Channels)
            {
                this.YAxes.Add(d.YAxis);
                this.RenderableSeries.Add(d.RenderableSeries);
                d.FifoCapacity = this.BufferSize;
            }
```

And the XAML is binding it.

```xml
        <sc:SciChartSurface x:Name="ChartSurface" Grid.Row="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" RenderableSeries="{sc:SeriesBinding RenderableSeries}" YAxes="{sc:AxesBinding YAxes}" Visibility="Hidden">
            <sc:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
                <sc:NumericAxis Name="XAxisControl" VisibleRange="{Binding SelectedRange}" DrawMajorGridLines="True" DrawMinorTicks="True"/>
            </sc:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
        </sc:SciChartSurface>

        <sc:SciChartSurface x:Name="OverviewSurface"
                            Background="White"
                            Grid.Row="2"
                            Grid.ColumnSpan="4"
                            Loaded="OnOverviewSurfaceLoaded"
                            RenderableSeries="{Binding ElementName=ChartSurface, Path=RenderableSeries}"
                            YAxes="{sc:AxesBinding YAxes}">
            <sc:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
                <sc:NumericAxis AutoRange="Always" DrawMajorGridLines="False" DrawMinorGridLines="False" DrawMajorBands="False" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
            </sc:SciChartSurface.XAxis>
        </sc:SciChartSurface>
```

I need to get it to a fixed range of 5000 to -5000.

Comment: Well, as soon as I posted I saw my mistake.  The minimum and maximum values are backward in the DoubleRange.  That fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the constructor for DoubleRange incorrectly, minimum is first, maximum is second.